# How to save a Data Frame column as a list? [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

I've a DataFrame and I want to save a column as as list in a text file, so far I'm doing this:

```
with open('file_name', 'w') as output:    
    output.write(str(df_phone_numbers['column']))
```

The problem I've here is that I'm already

handling the path with pandas

```
filepath_or_buffer='some_path' 
path_or_buf='some_output_path'
```

And I will prefer to keep consistency in this.

EDIT.

I don't want this file as a csv.

I'm currently saving the DataFrame as a csv

```
df.to_csv(path_or_buf='home/.../df.csv')
```

But I want this specific column, as a txt file in the format in which  is saved  with the above script but using pandas and not the:

> with open

function

Comment: "The problem I've here is that I'm already handling the path with pandas " Not sure what you mean by that. The code you have works, what is it you want to do differently?

Comment: It does work, but I'm saving other files in different directories and this one is saved in the 'the current directory'

Comment: " but using pandas and not the: with open". But why? `open` is the perfect way to save a plain text file.

Comment: You mention directories and paths. Perhaps you're looking for functionality like [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)? And you realise `open` can take a full path name, including its directories; not just the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'phone_number': ['555-111-2222', '555-111-3333']})

df.phone_number.to_csv('phone_numbers.csv')
```

and if you don't want the index:

```
df.phone_number.to_csv('phone_numbers.csv', index=False)
```

if you want a txt file, just change the filename.  The result is the same.

```
df.phone_number.to_csv('phone_numbers.txt', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

This code has equivalent results as your code.

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':[1,3],'column2':[4,5]})

>>>df['column1'].to_csv('file_name.txt',sep=' ')
>>>cat file_name.txt
0 1
1 3
```

Various other methods of saving your column as file_name.txt include:

```
>>>df.to_csv('file_name.txt',columns=['column1'],index=False) 
>>>cat file_name.txt
column1
a
b 

>>>df['column1'].to_csv('file_name.txt',index=False)
>>>cat file_name.txt
a
b

>>>df.to_csv('file_name.txt',columns=['column1'],index=False,line_terminator=',')
>>>cat file_name.txt
column1,a,b,
```